# ROR strip issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using strip for check email but it gave me this issues please help me out .

NoMethodError in UsersController#check_email 
undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass

```
  def check_email

    if params[:email].blank? 
    @email = params[:email].strip
    user = User.find_by_email(@email)
    if user.nil?
      text = "false"
    else
      text = "true"
    end
    render :text => text

  else
    render :text =>text
    end 
  end
```

Comment: `params[:email]` is nil. You need to figure out why. Maybe typo in the form field name or something?

Comment: Also did you mean `if params[:email].present?` (the opposite of `.blank?`)

Comment: What Sergio said. Also, your formatting is illegible. And you don't need to `render :text =>text` in both branches of the condition, just after the end once. And `text` is not even currently being assigned in your else path. `text = user.present?` would simplify the other path. `@email` has excessive scope, as you never reference it outside of the method...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the feedback by Sergio and Brad:

```ruby
def check_email
  text = params[:email].present? && User.where(email: params[:email].strip).exists?
  render :text => text
end
```

Comment: `User.where(email: email).exists?` is much more efficient, BTW.

Comment: I personally rather have a couple short lines instead of one long one, but will go with it for now. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Update it as:--

```
def check_email
  if params[:email].present? 
    @email = params[:email].strip
    user = User.find_by_email(@email)
    unless user.present?
      text = "false"
    else
      text = "true"
    end
    render :text => text
  else
    render :text =>text
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have small error, you need use:

```
unless params[:email].blank?
```

Or,

```
if params[:email].present?
```

I recommend to read about [blank? vs nil? vs empty? vs present?](http://pramodtech.quora.com/nil-empty-blank-present-in-Ruby-on-Rails)

Answer (score 0):

`if params[:email].blank?` should be `if params[:email].present?`.
Problem is when `params[:email]` is nil you are calling `strip` method on it i.e. `nil.strip`

So change it to followin

```
  def check_email
    if params[:email].present? 
      @email = params[:email].strip
      user = User.find_by_email(@email)
      text = user.nil? ? "false" : "true"
    else      
      text = "please enter email address"
    end 
    render :text =>text
  end
```